# Column repeating row values before TRUE values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a simple question. I am trying to create a column where it repeats the value before TRUE values of `grepl`. 
So, in a data.frame like that:
    `df <- data.frame(name = c("E11","M05","M05","E12","M05","E13","E14"))`

I was trying to use something like this unsuccessfully:
`df %>% mutate( clone = ifelse(grepl("M05",name), lag(name), ""))`

Here is the output I expect:

```
| name | clone |
+------+-------+
| E11  |       |
| M05  | E11   |
| M05  | E11   |
| E12  |       |
| M05  | E12   |
| E13  |       |
| E14  |       |
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create groups based using `cumsum` and `grepl` and fill `clone` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!grepl("M05",name))) %>%
  mutate(clone = ifelse(row_number() > 1, first(name), '')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  name  clone
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 E11   ""   
#2 M05   "E11"
#3 M05   "E11"
#4 E12   ""   
#5 M05   "E12"
#6 E13   ""   
#7 E14   ""
```

Comment: which 'first' function is this? I mean, from which package?

Comment: Because when I tried I got this error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"factor"’

Comment: @rodrigarco `first` is in `dplyr`. You can also use `name[1]` if you can't use `first` for some reason.

Comment: It's weird, when I tried the exact same code you wrote it gives me as `clone <- c("",1,1,"",2,"","")` . So it is not printing the names on the new column.

Comment: Ohh..I get it because `name` column is factor. Run `df$name <-as.character(df$name)` and try again.